# Compiling a program with a legacy version of gcc

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

This is probably a very difficult problem to troubleshoot with the information I can practically provide, but I'm hoping someone might be able to at least point me in a possible direction.

I'm trying to install HTK (http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/), which, according to [this](http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial/download) page needs to be installed using gcc 3.4. Their method of implementing backwards compatibility:

`#yum install compat-gcc-34-c++ compat-gcc-34`

won't work for me as I'm running Ubuntu (On that note, I take it I can't simply install YUM and the subsequent package, since it's an entirely different distro, but if I'm wrong I'd love to hear it).

I instead installed two versions of gcc 3.4 - 3.4.0 and 3.4.6 using instructions from [this](http://www.tellurian.com.au/whitepapers/multiplegcc.php) site. I then added the lines suggested by that page to the top of the makefile (on this note, what's the difference between makefile and makefile.in? I tried adding the lines to the top of both files regardless), both for version 3.4.0 and 3.4.6, but both failed. I also tried, on the off-chance, compiling it with my current version (4.4.1), but that also failed. I got the errors:

```
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/charles/bin/htk-3.4/HTKLib'
gcc  -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="i686"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I.    -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
HGraf.c:73:77: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
HGraf.c:74:23: error: X11/Xutil.h: No such file or directory
HGraf.c:75:21: error: X11/Xos.h: No such file or directory
HGraf.c:77:27: error: X11/keysymdef.h: No such file or directory
HGraf.c:87: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
HGraf.c:88: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rootW’
HGraf.c:91: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘theCmap’
HGraf.c:92: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘theGC’
HGraf.c:93: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gcs’
HGraf.c:95: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
HGraf.c:96: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘report’
HGraf.c:97: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘hints’
HGraf.c:111: error: ‘GXcopy’ undeclared here (not in a function)
HGraf.c:111: error: ‘GXor’ undeclared here (not in a function)
HGraf.c:111: error: ‘GXxor’ undeclared here (not in a function)
HGraf.c:111: error: ‘GXinvert’ undeclared here (not in a function)
HGraf.c:151: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
HGraf.c: In function ‘InstallFonts’:
HGraf.c:164: error: ‘FontInfo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:164: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
HGraf.c:164: error: for each function it appears in.)
HGraf.c:164: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XLoadQueryFont’
HGraf.c:164: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:167: error: ‘DefaultFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: At top level:
HGraf.c:176: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
HGraf.c: In function ‘HGetEvent’:
HGraf.c:219: error: ‘XEvent’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:219: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘xev’
HGraf.c:223: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XFlush’
HGraf.c:223: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:225: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XEventsQueued’
HGraf.c:225: error: ‘QueuedAfterFlush’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:226: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XNextEvent’
HGraf.c:226: error: ‘xev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:228: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:230: error: ‘ButtonPress’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:235: error: ‘ButtonRelease’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:240: error: ‘MotionNotify’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:245: error: ‘KeyPress’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:249: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DecodeKeyPress’
HGraf.c:251: error: ‘KeyRelease’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:257: error: ‘Expose’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HEventsPending’:
HGraf.c:281: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:281: error: ‘QueuedAfterFlush’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HMousePos’:
HGraf.c:288: error: ‘Window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:288: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘root’
HGraf.c:293: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XQueryPointer’
HGraf.c:293: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:293: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:293: error: ‘root’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:293: error: ‘child’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘InstallColours’:
HGraf.c:311: error: ‘XColor’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:311: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘greyDef’
HGraf.c:317: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XParseColor’
HGraf.c:317: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:317: error: ‘theCmap’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:317: error: ‘colourDef’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:320: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XAllocColor’
HGraf.c:334: error: ‘whiteDef’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:334: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XQueryColor’
HGraf.c:335: error: ‘blackDef’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:341: error: ‘greyDef’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HSetColour’:
HGraf.c:361: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSetForeground’
HGraf.c:361: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:361: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HSetGrey’:
HGraf.c:370: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:370: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HDrawLines’:
HGraf.c:388: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDrawLines’
HGraf.c:388: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:388: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:388: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:388: error: ‘XPoint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:388: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
HGraf.c: In function ‘HDrawRectangle’:
HGraf.c:395: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDrawRectangle’
HGraf.c:395: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:395: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:395: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HFillRectangle’:
HGraf.c:402: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XFillRectangle’
HGraf.c:402: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:402: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:402: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HDrawLine’:
HGraf.c:408: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDrawLine’
HGraf.c:408: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:408: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:408: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HFillPolygon’:
HGraf.c:414: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XFillPolygon’
HGraf.c:414: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:414: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:414: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:414: error: ‘XPoint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:414: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
HGraf.c: In function ‘HDrawArc’:
HGraf.c:427: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDrawArc’
HGraf.c:427: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:427: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:427: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HFillArc’:
HGraf.c:440: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XFillArc’
HGraf.c:440: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:440: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:440: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HPrintf’:
HGraf.c:451: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDrawString’
HGraf.c:451: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:451: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:451: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HCopyArea’:
HGraf.c:457: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XCopyArea’
HGraf.c:457: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:457: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:457: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HPlotVector’:
HGraf.c:476: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:476: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:476: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HSetFontSize’:
HGraf.c:490: error: ‘CurrentFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:490: error: ‘DefaultFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:499: error: ‘FontInfo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:502: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSetFont’
HGraf.c:502: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:502: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HSetLineWidth’:
HGraf.c:511: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSetLineAttributes’
HGraf.c:511: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:511: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:511: error: ‘LineSolid’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:511: error: ‘JoinRound’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:511: error: ‘FillSolid’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HSetXMode’:
HGraf.c:517: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:517: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘CentreX’:
HGraf.c:523: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XTextWidth’
HGraf.c:523: error: ‘CurrentFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘CentreY’:
HGraf.c:529: error: ‘CurrentFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HTextWidth’:
HGraf.c:535: error: ‘CurrentFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HTextHeight’:
HGraf.c:541: error: ‘CurrentFont’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HDrawImage’:
HGraf.c:550: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
HGraf.c:550: error: ‘xi’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:557: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDestroyImage’
HGraf.c:558: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XGetImage’
HGraf.c:558: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:558: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:558: error: ‘AllPlanes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:558: error: ‘XYPixmap’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:562: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XPutPixel’
HGraf.c:564: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XPutImage’
HGraf.c:564: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘HFlush’:
HGraf.c:570: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘InitGCs’:
HGraf.c:780: error: ‘XGCValues’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:780: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘values’
HGraf.c:783: error: ‘GCLineWidth’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:783: error: ‘GCFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:783: error: ‘GCForeground’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:785: error: ‘values’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:788: error: ‘gcs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:788: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XCreateGC’
HGraf.c:788: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:788: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:790: error: ‘GCPlaneMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘InitGlobals’:
HGraf.c:800: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DefaultScreen’
HGraf.c:800: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:801: error: ‘theCmap’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:801: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DefaultColormap’
HGraf.c:802: error: ‘rootW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:802: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RootWindow’
HGraf.c:803: error: ‘theGC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:803: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DefaultGC’
HGraf.c:804: error: ‘theVisual’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:804: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DefaultVisual’
HGraf.c:805: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DisplayCells’
HGraf.c:806: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DisplayWidth’
HGraf.c:807: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DisplayHeight’
HGraf.c:808: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘DisplayPlanes’
HGraf.c:809: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘WhitePixel’
HGraf.c:810: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BlackPixel’
HGraf.c: In function ‘MakeXGraf’:
HGraf.c:817: error: ‘Window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:817: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘window’
HGraf.c:818: error: ‘XSetWindowAttributes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:818: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘setwinattr’
HGraf.c:823: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:823: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XOpenDisplay’
HGraf.c:824: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XDisplayName’
HGraf.c:828: error: ‘parent’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:829: error: ‘window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:829: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XCreateSimpleWindow’
HGraf.c:831: error: ‘CWBackingStore’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:831: error: ‘setwinattr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:831: error: ‘WhenMapped’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:832: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XChangeWindowAttributes’
HGraf.c:834: error: ‘hints’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:834: error: ‘PPosition’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:834: error: ‘PSize’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:834: error: ‘PMaxSize’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:834: error: ‘PMinSize’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:841: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSetStandardProperties’
HGraf.c:841: error: ‘None’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:843: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSelectInput’
HGraf.c:843: error: ‘ExposureMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:843: error: ‘KeyPressMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:843: error: ‘ButtonPressMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:844: error: ‘ButtonReleaseMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:844: error: ‘PointerMotionHintMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:844: error: ‘PointerMotionMask’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:845: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XMapWindow’
HGraf.c:845: error: ‘theWindow’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:850: error: ‘report’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:851: error: ‘Expose’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:852: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XSendEvent’
HGraf.c:852: error: ‘False’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c: In function ‘TermHGraf’:
HGraf.c:861: error: ‘theDisp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
HGraf.c:862: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘XCloseDisplay’
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/charles/bin/htk-3.4/HTKLib'
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are missing the X11 development packages.

Comment: Thank you, that was the trouble. Feel rather silly, but with all the complication of installing a legacy version of gcc, I assumed that must have been the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The very first error may indicate the cause:

```
error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

At one time one needed to set $INCLUDE_PATH for gcc.

Answer (score 1):

So, the presence of a makefile.in indicates that the program is using autoconf.  That being the case, I suggest you put both the makefile and makefile.in back the way they were, and instead redo the configure step:

`GCC_VERSION=3.4.0 PREFIX=/usr/local/gcc/${GCC_VERSION}/bin/ CC=${PREFIX}gcc CPP=${PREFIX}g++ ./configure`

Obviously, you should edit that to match the actual version of the compiler and path where you installed it, along with adding any extra configure arguments you need.

Comment: I tried this, but got the error 'C preprocessor "#{PREFIX}g++" fails sanity check. I assumed this was because the program was written in C, and removed the CPP= section. It thus configured, and the makefile included the line CC = /usr/local... (Makefile.in instead had the line CC = @CC@, but since this is the case for virtually all of its variables, I assume it's some sort of command to pull the value from elsewhere. Nevertheless, I got the same errors. Let my try dealing with the X11 issue some have mentioned and see how that goes.

Comment: #{PREFIX}g++ is a typo... should be ${PREFIX}g++

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the X11-devel package installed? Looks like an abject lack of X11 header files.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `gcc-3.4` from Ubuntu repos (`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.3`).

Then configure the project using `./configure CC="gcc-4.3"` and make as usual.

This might not work, but point you in the right direction.

EDIT: The X11 development libraries on Ubuntu are named `libx11-dev` but they might not be the only development libraries you are missing: read the errors and try to guess what other libraries you are missing (if you note that a header is missing try searching http://packages.ubuntu.com for the file name and add the relative package using `sudo apt-get install`).

Comment: trying to install gcc-3.4 results in error Couldn't find package gcc-3.4, I'm guessing it's simply too old.

Comment: It was in dapper, then was moved to the "universe" repositories until jaunty. For karmic and lucid it seems to be missing. If your project is in C you might be lucky installing the development libraries and than configuring without the CC option (or providing the full path to your gcc).

Answer (score 0):

The first set of errors is

```
HGraf.c:73:77: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory 
HGraf.c:74:23: error: X11/Xutil.h: No such file or directory 
HGraf.c:75:21: error: X11/Xos.h: No such file or directory 
HGraf.c:77:27: error: X11/keysymdef.h: No such file or directory
```

i.e. your compiler can't find the X11 headers. These will probably be somewhere like `/usr/X11R6/include`. Try adding that include path to your make command, like

```
make CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/X11R6/include"
```

If the makefile is nonstandard you might have to edit it to insert this path. If you've run a configure script reconfigure with

```
./configure CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/X11R6/include" # Include any other options
```